# FPDF error: Not a JPEG file: http://10.11.201.93:81/webdocc/uploaded/tes3.jpg

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I am working with fpdf to convert html to pdf . I have the following html in new.html .

```
<title></title>
<p><img alt="" height="364" src="http://10.11.201.93:81/webdocc/uploaded/tes3.jpg" width="496" /><img alt="" height="470" src="http://10.11.201.93:81/webdocc/uploaded/tes4.jpg" width="641" /></p>
```

The code to convert html to pdf is as following :

```
<?php
require('html2fpdf.php');
$pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$fp = fopen("new.html","r");
$strContent = fread($fp, filesize("new.html"));
fclose($fp);
$pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
$pdf->Output("new.pdf");
echo "PDF file is generated successfully!";
?>
```

But when I run this code , I am getting the following error .

```
FPDF error: Not a JPEG file: http://10.11.201.93:81/webdocc/uploaded/tes3.jpg
```

On the following html code , I am getting error "Alpha channel not supported" .

```
<h1 id="sample_title"><img alt="" src="http://10.11.201.84/document-editor/uploaded/applet.PNG" style="width: 514px; height: 204px;" /></h1>
```

How can I remove this errors ? Please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same problem much time then I started to read all code of **FPDF**.
I got my solution by changing some line **fpdf.php**. **FPDF.php** is core file in **FPDF** Library. So keep backup of this file before any change.

In this file I just searched

> Not a JPEG file

then i comment out this line and set a default value

> //$this->Error('Not a JPEG file: '.$file);
>
> $colspace ="DeviceRGB";

After this, my **PDF** going generate.
Note that in my case Image path was valid and i was upload image on **S3** using **base64 Decode** also **Croping** too. so that maybe my image going working wrong. but it was being open on the browser. So after two change on **fpdf.php**. I got my solution.

Another thing you have to check is the image path is valid or not. in pdf file i am using

> $pdf->Image($file,12,12,30,30);

Answer (score 1):

For "Not a JPEG file":
Your best bet here is to re-export the image file. Just open it up in Gimp, Photo Shop, etc and re-export as a jpeg. Every time I've had that come up, I've just re-exported with Gimp and it fixed whatever FPDF thought was the non-jpeg part of the image.

For "Alpha channel not supported":
This is because FPDF does NOT support the Alpha channel. I believe it does support Index transparency so you can re-save the image (again Gimp, Photo Shop, etc) with the alpha channel off and Index transparency on.

You may also want to checkout [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) it is a HTML TO PDF converter that does support the alpha channel. If it is a large PDF you're generating (many pages, images, etc) you may need to increase the execution time.

One more thing you can check out too, is a fan made support for Alpha in FPDF [Alpha Channels / Masks](http://fpdf.de/downloads/add-ons/alpha-channels-masks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have found that constructing slideshows with Paintbrush on a MacBook Pro for years have sometimes been saving what "file jpeg_filename.jpg" determines is a PNG, as a JPEG, which is not the end of the world as far as the browsers go rendering this.  Within FPDF's fpdf.php I fixed my own shortcomings that were resulting in "FPDF Error: Not a JPEG file" via the kludgy "if($a[2]==3) { return $this->_parsepng($file); }" additional codeline below ...

```
function _parsejpg($file)
{
  // Extract info from a JPEG file
  $a = getimagesize($file);
  if(!$a)
    $this->Error('Missing or incorrect image file: '.$file);
  if($a[2]==3) { return $this->_parsepng($file); }
  if($a[2]!=2)
    $this->Error('Not a JPEG file: '.' '.$a[2].' '.$file);
  if(!isset($a['channels']) || $a['channels']==3)
    $colspace = 'DeviceRGB';
  elseif($a['channels']==4)
    $colspace = 'DeviceCMYK';
  else
    $colspace = 'DeviceGray';
  $bpc = isset($a['bits']) ? $a['bits'] : 8;
  $data = file_get_contents($file);
  return array('w'=>$a[0], 'h'=>$a[1], 'cs'=>$colspace, 'bpc'=>$bpc, 'f'=>'DCTDecode', 'data'=>$data);
}
```