# Cannot extract image into PDF

Tags: php, fpdf, jpgraph

I am using `jpgraph` library for charts and `FPDF` for copying the chart image into PDF. I am able to view the chart on the website but I cannot copy the chart as an image onto the PDF. The error I am receiving is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unsupported image type: php in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php(884): FPDF->Error('Unsupported ima...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\generate_pdfTest.php(54): FPDF->Image('http://localhos...', 10, 10, 50.8, 33.866666666667) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271
```

The code for generating PDF is:

```
<?php
//include connection file
ob_start();
include_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');



class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
    $this->Cell(276, 5, 'Details', 0, 0, 'C');
    $this->Ln();
    $this->SetFont('Times', '', 12);
    $this->Cell(276, 10, 'Details of students', 0, 0, 'C');
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}

}



$pdf=new PDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->SetTextColor(44,44,44);
$pdf->Image('http://localhost/Test.php', 10, 10, 25.4/150* 300,  25.4/150*200);
sleep(3);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);


$pdf->Output("D", "1.pdf");
ob_end_flush(); 

?>
```

and the code for generating chart is:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"

require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');



$data1y=array(47,80,40,116);
$data2y=array(61,30,82,105);
$data3y=array(115,50,70,93);


// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(350,200,'auto');

$graph->img->SetImgFormat('jpeg');


$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,30,60,90,120,150), array(15,45,75,105,135));
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
$b3plot = new BarPlot($data3y);

// Create the grouped bar plot
$gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot,$b3plot));
// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($gbplot);


$b1plot->SetColor("white");
$b1plot->SetFillColor("#cc1111");

$b2plot->SetColor("white");
$b2plot->SetFillColor("#11cccc");

$b3plot->SetColor("white");
$b3plot->SetFillColor("#1111cc");

$graph->title->Set("Bar Plots");

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the image type (6th parameter):

```
$pdf->Image('http://localhost/Test.php', 10, 10, 25.4/150*300, 25.4/150*200, 'JPG');
```

Remark: PNG is generally a better choice for charts.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I tried to use JPG/PNG but ended up getting this error. If I change it to JPG ``` Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file``` and if I change it to PNG ```Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Not a PNG file: Test.php```

Comment: The declared type must match the real type. Your script creates a JPEG. If you want a PNG instead, change the call to `SetImgFormat()`.

Comment: Yes I did change it both sides, yet I received the errors.

Comment: The error ```Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: Test.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php(1242): FPDF->Error('Missing or inco...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php(885): FPDF->_parsejpg('Test.php') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\generate_pdfTest.php(63): FPDF->Image('Test.php', 10, 10, 50.8, 33.866666666667, 'jpg') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271```

Comment: From the message, it seems you removed the URL and kept just the file name...

Comment: I tried to add the url as well : ```http://localhost/test_db/generate_pdfTest.php``` Yet the error is same

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't accept connections from localhost. Try with the real server name.

Comment: @Oliver The problem was in FPDF file. I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568423/fpdf-error-not-a-jpeg-file-http-10-11-201-9381-webdocc-uploaded-tes3-jpg. and I changed it to PNG and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The image is too small. Can I place it in center and large? How can i do this?